# Azure Cosmos DB decode base64 in stored procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I need to decode a base64 encoded string in a stored procedure in Azure CosmosDB. I tried to use the following functions, but for each of them I'm getting not defined error:

- [base64_decode_tostring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/base64_decode_tostringfunction)
- atob()

I ended up with creating a custom function using [this algorithm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64), but it doesn't seem like a good practice.

Is there a built in function?

```js
var defaultGroupId = groupIds.filter(id => {
    // atob(id); base64_decode_tostring(id); are not working
    let decoded = base64_decode(id);
    return decoded.indexOf(defaultGroupIndicator) == 0;
});

function base64_decode(s) {
    // took from the link above;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are using base64 string as your id?

Comment: it's how the model is structured on our project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't provide utility methods other than those provided as part of the JS spec itself. btoa and atob are not a part of that. If you need this functionality then your best(only) option is to use any of the open source implementations that are available.

I also want to point out that if you are doing high volume reads using stored procedures you may want to rethink that. Stored procedures are best used when doing high volume bulk writes. Stored procedures only operate on the primary replica in our four replica set. As such you will not see all of the provisioned throughput when all of your reads are on the primary replica and not using any of the secondaries.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The main goal here is to reduce DB request rate to avoid DB throttling, so basically you're saying that it's better to make a several calls from SDK instead of one, because these several calls will be split across DB replicas, and the stored procedure will be executed only on the main replica? In my case it's not a high volume read, but it will be occurring many (> 2k) times once a day.

Comment: Why would you need to make several calls for this operation? You should model your data such that you can retrieve it with a query in one operation. When you use stored procedures you can only saturate a quarter of your provisioned throughput. So unless you are doing things like bulks insert/update operations you will need to provision more RU/s to get an equivalent level of throughput vs. just doing regular queries via SDK.